# Find the sum of $\sum (n^2+n)x^n$ using integrals

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, differential-geometry, power-series

I'm having a difficult to find $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n^2+n)x^n$. the solution is $\frac{2x}{(1-x)^3}$.

This is my solution:

$$1.   \space\space\space\space S(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (n^2 +n)x^n =$$

$$2. \space\space\space\space \sum_{n=1}^\infty n(n+1)x^n.$$

$$3. \space\space\space\space \int S(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n(n+1)\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n+1}$$

$$4. \space\space\space\space \int S(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}$$

$$5. \space\space\space\space \frac{1}{x^2}\int S(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}$$

$$6.\space\space\space\space \int\big(\frac{1}{x^2}\int S(x)\big) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n\frac{x^{n}}{n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n} = \frac{x}{1-x}.$$

$$7.\space\space\space\space\frac{1}{x^2}\int S(x) = \bigg(\frac{x}{1-x}\bigg)' = \frac{1}{({x-1})^2}$$

$$8. \space\space\space\space\frac{1}{x^2}S(x) = \bigg(\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}\bigg)' = -\frac{2}{(x-1)^3}.$$

$$9.\space\space\space\space S(x) = -\frac{2x^2}{(x-1)^3} $$

My solution is wrong.

I numbered every step, where is my problem? I have tomorrow test so I'd love if you can help me. thanks in advance!

Comment: I am surprised, the standard way is by using *derivatives*.

Comment: In 7. you should derivate $\frac{x}{1-x}$

Comment: @AndréNicolas This is how my professor showed me..

Comment: @user110822 You're right, I typed too fast, in my page I derivated $\frac{x}{1-x}$. thanks you for notify me, edit

Comment: Problem is line 7. You should use rule for product for left side. Or to transfer $1/x^2$ to right side, and then to take derivate. And in line 4. its $x^{n+1}$, typo.

Comment: @user110822 Can you please explain more detail?

Comment: when you take derivate of left side ($7 \to 8$), you want $\frac{d}{dx} (1/x^2 \cdot \int S(x))$, so you can't just throw $1/x^2$  like constant. It's better to write $\int S(x) = \frac{x^2}{(x-1)^2}$ and then to attack with derivate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everithing is fine untill line 7:
$$\frac1{x^2}\int{S(x)}=\frac1{(x-1)^2}$$
The problem was that you derived first, just then multiplied by $x^2$.
deriving both sides gives, by the multiplication rule:
$$-\frac{3}{x^3}\int{S(x)}+\frac{1}{x^2}S(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$

And not as mentioned. Doing it in the other way, multiplying first then derive, gives:
$$\int{S(x)}=\frac{x^2}{(x-1)^2}=(\frac{x}{x-1})^2\\
S(x) = [(\frac{x}{x-1})^2]'=2(\frac{x}{x-1})(\frac{-1}{(x-1)^2})\\
S(x) = -2\frac{x}{(x-1)^3}=\frac{2x}{(1-x)^3}
$$

Comment: I owe you a half of my grade :-) thank you so much!